# Is using text to speech api allowed in android app?

Tags: android

the following link gives me speech in Arabic by using google translate server side api , some website descripe that using this is illegal is this true or not ? because I want to added it to my android application. 
P.S : android os does not support Arabic speech

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ar&q=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7

Comment: why shouldn´t it be? It´s part of Android OS...

Comment: i am asking about the server side api , that some website descripe it as illegal , is this true or not ?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-text-to-speech-on-android-to-read-out-incoming-messages--cms-22524

Please Google "text to speech android tutorial" you'll get many.

**Edit:**  Sorry , I understood you question wrong.

I believe it is. But if you are really concerned, please contact Google or ask on their forums, I dont think you'll get an answer to that here. Good luck!

Comment: my friend . the built in feature tts in android os does not support arabic language so i have found that google translate server api  has the ability to convert Arabic text to speech , some website describe using the above link is illegal and i don't want to lose my Google play account by using this feature , for that reason i am asking , is this legal or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Terms of Service in Google Translate API:

### 1. Prohibitions

**You will not knowingly use the API to create, train, or improve (directly or 
indirectly) a substantially similar product or service, including any other machine translation engine.**

That means, for my understanding, that if You plan something like this, it is not allowed if it is Your own implementation of a translate engine. For example, You are calling Your app "Hussamabd´s great Translation Engine" and this app is really for translate words into other languages, then it is not allowed. BUT, there is another part in the API:

### Introduction

**This document is intended for developers who want to write applications that can interact with the Google Translate API. Google Translate is a tool that automatically translates text from one language to another language (e.g. French to English). You can use the Google Translate API to programmatically translate text in your webpages or apps.**

This means to me, if You create an app, which intention is not to translate words, but You need this translation for any other reason, for example making Your app in every language, it will be ok.

Also, You have to pay some fees for using this API. But to get really sure, You should contact Google or a lawyer, because I am not and I can´t give You any law confirmed statement!